# How to execute multiple commands with sudo in script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-12.04, sudoers

Can we use heredocs to run multiple commands using sudo?

I am facing an issue (need to pass password for every command) while running 
multiple commands:

```
echo 'password'| sudo -S ls
echo 'password'| sudo -S cat /var/log/abc.log
```

Can anyone help me how to automate this in a script? Like:

```
echo 'password' | sudo -S << ENDBLOCK
ls
cat
ENDBLOCK
```

Comment: `sudo` will remember the password used for a short period (5 minutes by default), so there should be no need to supply the password to the second call if the first doesn't take long to run. However, a better solution is to configure `sudo` to allow your specific commands to be run without supplying a password, which keeps the password out of the script altogether.

Answer (score 6):

you can run `sh -c ...`, but remember to quote properly.

```
sudo sh -c 'id; echo another command ; id'
```

`sudo` must see this as a single argument for the `sh` command.

Of course you can use new line instead of semicolon:

```
sudo sh -c '
  echo "I am root"
  id
  echo "another command"
  id
'
```

Comment: Could you please help me how it goes when we run it remotely

Comment: I can try if you specify the problem. What exactly you try to do and how it fails? Run it via ssh?

Comment: In my script, I will login to the VM with sudo user say "sasi" then I need to execute few commands like "mv", "sed" etc. Then I am facing the below issue sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
Sorry, try again.

Comment: sorry for delay. In this situation consider creating script on remote machine to do the job and declare NOPASSWD: tag in /etc/sudoers for this script. You can sudo it then without password. BTW, remember to upvote my answer ;-)

Comment: Is there any alternative other than adding NOPASSWD to sudoers.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to write a script with all the things you need to do with sudo and then run the script with sudo.

Answer (score 1):

you could put all your commands in a script. Then

- sudo ./script.sh
- put permissions for script.sh in /etc/sudoers.d; that way you'll never need to type your password again (for that script)